# How to check variable is in array or not in angular and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular6

> I am using angular 6 with laravel. I am fetching one array to frontend
>   and i want to check that my variable is into array or not. In php just
>   like `in_array` function. I am using below function `includes` to
>   check my variable with array. But some time it works and some times
>   its not working. It provides error of `RROR TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'includes' of undefined`.

After some time when i used to reload page multiple times my code starts to work well.

```
public id:any[];
public status1:boolean = false;
public status2:boolean = false;
    if(this.id.includes('5'))
       {
         this.status1 = true;
       }
    else if(this.id.includes('17'))
      {
         this.status2 = true;
      }
```

my api gives me proper data : `["17","18"]`.
But i dont understand some time its works and some time its not working.I used to update my package.json too but still its not working all time.
Is there any other way to find variable within array like in php we are having `in_array` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign empty Array to your Id property, currently your declaring it as array but the initial value will be `undefined`

```
 public id:any[] = [];
```

after this assign your api data to it.